# Coordinate geometry basic, triangles

Tags: analytic-geometry, triangles

In the figure below, what are the values of x and y?

[image: Figure]

Now, y cooridinate will be b-k.
But how to calculate the x coordinate? Pythagoras theorem seems to be of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line segment seems through (x,y) seems to be parallel to the x-axis. If you use similar triangles, you can find out the required length.

Let (0,b) be point B, origin be 0, and (a,0) be point A, (x,y) be X and (0,b-k) be K. So $\Delta$BKX is similar to $\Delta$BOA. Hence,

$\frac{BK}{BO}=\frac{KX}{OA}$

$\frac{k}{b}=\frac{x}{a}$

$x=\frac{ak}{b}$

Comment: Well that was very easy! Thanks for this :)